# timepicker in Telerik mvc grid edit and insert mode

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, timepicker

I working on telerik mvc grid. My requirement is timepicker in mvc grid edit mode .

how to create time picker in telerik mvc grid please give me any example.

thanks and regards
shanker.B

Answer (score 2):

You need to define an editor template for that property and use the DateTimePicker in it. You can check the DateTime.ascx file which is distributed with Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: But how to populate data to the EditorTemplate during data binding?

Comment: @zsong:
I actually had to do this recently. During the data binding, you need to populate the UIHint property with the value of the datum.